# While loop to take user input not taking the last inputted value

Tags: c++, input, while-loop

I'm quite new to coding, so I don't quite understand why this while loop is not taking the last inputted value. The output at the end if you were to type in "1, 2, 3, 4, 5" would be "4, 3, 2, 1". Any help would be much appreciated.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <queue>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    priority_queue<int> q;

    int score;

    cin >> score;

    int count = 0;

    while (count != 4)
    {
        count++;
        q.push(score);
        cin >> score;
    }

    while (!q.empty())
    {
        cout << q.top() << " ";
        q.pop();
    }
}
```

Comment: You never `q.push(score);` after the last `cin >> score;`. Try stepping through your code with a debugger to see what happens to `q`.

Comment: Your structure is a little odd. Simply move the `cin` before the `push`, remove the `cin` outside the loop, and stop the loop when `count` is 5.

Comment: Thank you for your help. I completely forgot I had another input above the while loop.

Comment: A talk with the duck is in order... See [How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/), don't laugh, it works...

Answer (score 0):

It's because you never do `q.push(score);` after the last `cin >> score;` in your first `while` cycle. That means the queue only saves 4 integers, which causes the next while cycle to print only four numbers.
The code down below will print you five numbers.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <queue>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    priority_queue<int> q;

    int score;

    int count = 0;

    while (count != 5)
    {
        cin >> score;
        q.push(score);
        count++;
    }

    while (!q.empty())
    {
        cout << q.top() << " ";
        q.pop();
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int arr[5], n = 5;

int main() {
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
        cin >> arr[i];
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        n--;
        cout << arr[n] << endl;
    }
}
```